# Error appears while configuring apache2 server in ubuntu 12.04lts

Tags: apache2

Error which I got while configuring apache2 server:

```
Inspiron-3541:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ service apache2 reload 
/usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 87: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
apache2: Syntax error on line 237 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the error this file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite doesn't exist (perhaps you have deleted or renamed it).

If that is not the problem check the messages in the error log (which should be located by default in /var/log/apache2/error.log)

Comment: ya it is thier  in folder ...

Comment: Can you see its contents via         cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite